# Postgresql 13 Installation failing on Ubuntu 20.04 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, systemctl

I've been trying to install PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 20.04 (VPS) but I always get an error.

[I followed this article to install it.](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-postgresql-13-on-ubuntu/)

**EDIT:** I also followed the [instructions from the PostgreSQL website](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) to install it from repository. I get the same error.

The line that breaks the installation is here (2nd time I try to install it):

```
$ sudo apt install postgresql-13 postgresql-client-13
```

It outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
postgresql-13 is already the newest version (13.1-1.pgdg20.04+1).
postgresql-client-13 is already the newest version (13.1-1.pgdg20.04+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up postgresql-common (223.pgdg20.04+1) ...
Not replacing deleted config file /etc/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf
Building PostgreSQL dictionaries from installed myspell/hunspell packages...
Removing obsolete dictionary files:
Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-11-18 17:57:53 UTC; 13ms ago
       Docs: man:postgres(1)
    Process: 16459 ExecStart=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 16459 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Nov 18 17:57:53 localhost systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
Nov 18 17:57:53 localhost systemd[16459]: postgresql.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Nov 18 17:57:53 localhost systemd[16459]: postgresql.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres: No such file or directory
Nov 18 17:57:53 localhost systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Nov 18 17:57:53 localhost systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 18 17:57:53 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-common (--configure):
 installed postgresql-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-13:
 postgresql-13 depends on postgresql-common (>= 182~); however:
  Package postgresql-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package postgresql-13 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-common
 postgresql-13
```

Then I try to check the status of postgresql.service:

```
$ systemctl status postgresql.service
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-11-18 17:57:53 UTC; 15s ago
       Docs: man:postgres(1)
    Process: 16459 ExecStart=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 16459 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

Can you give me some insights on how to deal with this issue ?

Comment: Uninstall the software, remove all leftovers, then follow the instructions from the PostgreSQL site.

Comment: I've uninstalled it [following this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32730/how-to-remove-postgres-from-my-installation), removed all leftovers then followed the instructions [from the postgreSQL site](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/). I have the same error.